# Select multiple rows from a table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this query to select a row from table:-

```
select identifier, name from content where rawid=
        (select contentid from content where rawid='002cd122-f604-4093-b242-1bd12eafaceb')
```

I want a query which will select all rows from `content` such that each row corresponds to a `rawid` from another table, called rawIdentifiers.
I want to give rawid from this table, rawIdentifiers:-

[image]

For example, this query will give me one row:-

```
select identifier, name from content where rawid=
            (select contentid from content where rawid='00504a25-bc6a-4edd-8c30-cb57e12b7c3d')
```

this will give other row:

```
    select identifier, name from content where rawid=
                    (select contentid from content where rawid='002cd122-f604-4093-b242-1bd12eafaceb')
```

and so on.

I want one query to get all the rows in a table. How can I do that?

Comment: It sounds like you need to do a join.  It will be hard to provide the syntax without the DDL for both tables.  Could you post the DDL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to do a join. You may want to read up on joins so that you can understand what exactly they are doing. I think you want something along the lines of:

```
select identifier, name 
from content 
inner join rawidentifiers ON content.identifier = rawidentifiers.identifier
```

I'm not sure of your exact table structure so I'm guessing about the column names.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want an inner join to do the matching for you. Since you didn't provide the table structure for your `content` table I tried to combine pieces of your sample code to give you a working example:

```
select identifier, name 
from content 
inner join content ON rawid = (select contentid from content where rawid='00504a25-bc6a-4edd-8c30-cb57e12b7c3d')
```

The idea here is to get all records from `content` but every record has another record from `content` joined to it. The join is done similar to your `where` clause for 1 record.